# Syntax error when using join with delete statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can't figure out why I'm getting a syntax error with this delete statement:

```
DELETE FROM RawServiceNow.dbo.u_loan
LEFT JOIN RawServiceNow.stg.ServiceNowDeletes ON 
RawServiceNow.stg.ServiceNowDeletes.SysId = RawServiceNow.dbo.u_loan.SysId WHERE 
ServiceNowDeltes.SysId IS NULL
```

**Error:**

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'LEFT'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
DELETE u
FROM RawServiceNow.dbo.u_loan u
LEFT JOIN RawServiceNow.stg.ServiceNowDeletes s 
ON s.SysId = u.SysId 
WHERE s.SysId IS NULL
```